# Max Inventory SQL Query

Tags: sql

I need to write a query that displays our inventory for products that we have 500 or more of. The problem is that we don't want our customers seeing our exact inventory. How could I develop a query that would show the actual quantity available up to 500, but only show ‘500’ for any inventory that exceeds the 500 count.

Select item, qtyavailable from stock

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hint:  `case` can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with `CASE`:

```
select item, 
  (case 
    when qtyavailable > 500 
      then 500 
    else 
      qtyavailable 
    end) as quantity_available 
from stock
```

If your RDBMS supports the `LEAST()` function you may be able to use that:

```
select item, 
  least(qtyavailable,500) as quantity_available 
from stock
```

Comment: The first query worked great! Thanks for the quick reply. Greatly appreciate the help Ike